# ImportError: DLL load failed. "imp.py" not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

**EDIT-- I tried to install TensorFlow after gettting this message, and it seemed to install fine, up until I ran a check, when it came up with a similar error to the one below.**

I am trying to use DeepFakeLab, and I keep getting this error message.

```
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\DeepFaceLab\joblib\SubprocessorBase.py", line 59, in _subprocess_run
    self.on_initialize(client_dict)
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\DeepFaceLab\mainscripts\Extractor.py", line 68, in on_initialize
    nnlib.import_all (device_config)
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\DeepFaceLab\nnlib\nnlib.py", line 756, in import_all
    nnlib.import_keras(device_config)
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\DeepFaceLab\nnlib\nnlib.py", line 165, in import_keras
    nnlib._import_tf(device_config)
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\DeepFaceLab\nnlib\nnlib.py", line 134, in _import_tf
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\benja\Documents\Program Files\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLabCUDA10.1AVX\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I am not very versed in coding, so I don't really understand what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Did you install tensorflow?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It would be a good idea to format any code or exception block to be more readable.